# Error code P200A on 2013 Kia Sorrento

Tags: kia, code, sorrento

Does anyone know if I have to replace the intake manifold or can I try something cheaper first. I did see a little anti freeze leaked . Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 4):

That code is for "**Intake Manifold Runner Performance Bank 1**". That does not automatically mean the manifold needs to be replaced. These are the common reasons for the code;

1. Intake manifold runner control actuator failure
2. Powertrain Control Module (PCM) failure
3. Restricted vacuum lines

I'd start with #3 to see if it is as simple as a vacuum line. The other two are more complex and may require a qualified mechanic to be involved to troubleshoot.